# I want to create Dashboard to my proceed data using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I want to create dashboard for my data. firstly I completed processing of data using Hadoop framework,and I completed some use cases also..now from the use cases out put I want to display them in a website like in a graphical manner through tablue I got some visualizations but I want to integrate those graphs into my website(dashboard) how can I?
 Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link, might be useful for you.

http://gethue.com/hadoop-search-dynamic-search-dashboards-with-solr/

Comment: Thank you Krishna...but I want to integrate this dashboard into my website  how can i?